# When does nginx as a proxy server sends 502 bad gateway error?

Tags: php, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have an nginx proxy server which receives client requests, and requests php5-fpm to process them.
I want to know, in case of heavy load, when does nginx sends 502 error?
Is it something bad while nginx requests php5-fpm and php5-fpm can't handle them or is it nginx finds out that it is too much request and directly sends back 502 response?

**Edit**

**Code 1**

```
location / {
 error_page 502 @static;
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
 proxy_intercept_errors on;
}

location @static{

}
```

**Code 2**

```
error_page 502 @static;

location / {
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
location @static{

}
```

I have seen that code 2 works just fine, in case of heavy load.
But code 1 doesn't work, can someone explain that?

Also, the $uri in @static location equals '/index.php' and not the actual uri.
Is there a way to find actual uri?

Comment: Let’s imagine your php daemon stops working, or gets overloaded by requests, it will not work properly and the all the php requests from nginx would not be served, so a 502 http error will appear. Nginx can't find out anything, it's an program and doesn't know the second parties code, ability or flaws.

Comment: so you mean that it happens in between nginx and php5-fpm talk.

Comment: It can happen with nginx and `php5-fpm`, but it can also happen with others, if nginx talks with them. But in most cases it's just `php5-fpm`.

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois, please check out edit.

Comment: Code1 doesn't work because `try_files` makes internal redirect to `/index.php` that processed in other location (probably `location ~ \.php$`, or something like that) and first location is completely forgotten, so `error_page` directive there is not used anymore. `proxy_intercept_errors` in code1 will not work also.

Comment: I think i am getting it. so is this correct? *try_files $uri @static", so if there is heavy load, i can still use uri in @static.

Comment: and even if there is not much load, and nothing found in $uri, then also I can use uri in @static